# How to compile pyqt5 and python code in cython

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, cython

Is it possible to compile my project with python3 with pyqt5 with cython?

I have created a compyle.py file with these content:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
ext_modules = [
    Extension("Main",  ["Main.py"]),
    Extension("MainWindow",  ["MainWindow.py"]),
    Extension("CopyDialog",  ["CopyDialog.py"]),
    Extension("CopyDebugThread",  ["CopyDebugThread.py"])

]
setup(
    name = 'My Program Name',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

and i run this file with this comment according [this](https://medium.com/@xpl/protecting-python-sources-using-cython-dcd940bb188e):

```
python3 compile.py build_ext --inplace
```

But i got this error:

```
$ python3 compile.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
cythoning Main.py to Main.c
/home/groot/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:367: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: /home/groot/PythonProject/ConfigServer/Main.py
  tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from MainWindow import MainWindowApp

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWindow = MainWindowApp()
sys.exit(app.exec())            ^
------------------------------------------------------------

Main.py:7:13: Expected an identifier
building 'Main' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c Main.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/Main.o
Main.c:1:2: error: #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
 #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
  ^~~~~
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I think cython can compile `PyQt5` module? How could i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although python tolerates using `app.exec()`, cython is stricter, the solution is to use `app.exec_()`:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from MainWindow import MainWindowApp

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWindow = MainWindowApp()
sys.exit(app.exec_()) # <---
```

Comment: I presume this is because Cython still defaults to interpreting code as Python 2. I'd guess setting the language level to 3 would also work (since `exec` would no longer be a statement)

Comment: @DavidW It could be but officially the function is app.exec_(), although as indicated also app.exec() is tolerated. IMHO uses exec_() and you avoid compatibility problems

Comment: @eyllanesc dude after compiled how could i run this files? https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/y38TZvkSfh/

Comment: @sayreskabir Cython does not generate an application that can be executed in itself, but a library that must be imported. I recommend you to investigate what Cython is, what it does, and what it serves for, so you understand what you must do to execute your app